# Error found when loading /home/[User]/.profile

Tags: boot, error-handling

I installed homebrew last night to enable me to install wtfutil terminal on my Ubuntu 20.4. I did successfully and later decided to uninstall it.

It seems that it uninstalled alright but left some errors that I don't understand. I'm new to Ubuntu/Linux so this troubles me a lot since I cannot access my desktop after entering my password.

Here is the full error:

```
Error found when loading /home/[user]/.profile

/home/[user]/.profile: line 28: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew: No such file or directory 

As a result the session will not be configured correctly.
You should fix the problem as soon as feasible.
```

Comment: Do you know how to edit a text file using the command line? (If not, look it up). Your output tells you exactly which file you need to fix, and even exactly which line of that file is the problem. If you don't understand that line, copy it and post it [in your question above](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1251939/edit).

Comment: Sorry, but when I enter my password then I get that error. There's no way to use my terminal at this point

Comment: Then don't login to the desktop. At the login screen, use CTRL+ALT+F3 to reach a text-only TTY login.

Comment: That worked, boss. I also see the same error (-bash: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew: No such file or directory) at the bottom.

Please what do I do next?

Comment: I looked how to create a text file up

Comment: You don't *create* a text file. You are *editing* an existing text file. You are removing the changes you made what you installed brew. It's a fairly important file, so don't get frustrated and nuke it. Advice: Try using the `nano` editor. Create a test file using nano, then go back in and successfully edit that test file using nano. Then you will be ready to edit the real file.

Comment: I'm very sorry but I am completely new to Ubuntu. I'd really appreciate any help because I've had to reinstall over 5 times already, each time I ran into an issue I couldn't find a fix for. I can't afford that now. Please help

Comment: Sorry, that last comment was sent before yours. I have been able to create, save and edit a file with nano editor. Thank you

Comment: Then you are all set to `nano /home/[user]/.profile`, and scroll down to line 28. Depending upon which install instructions you followed, there might be more brew-related script on lines 29 and 30.

Comment: I'm there. Since I uninstalled brew, am I supposed to remove that line? I can see it on line 28

Here: eval $(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)

Comment: It is the only line of text in white color, if that means anything

Comment: Delete that line! (Remember to Save afterward). Once the brew line(s) are deleted and the change saved, try logout/login. The command to logout from a TTY is `exit`. The Key Combo to return to the GUI login is CTRL+ALT+F2 (or F1)

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer below by clicking the '*Answer your question*' button. It's absolutely fine (and very much encouraged) to [self-answer your question](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer), but adding a solution to the question itself is not (and neither is adding "Solved" to the title). Also "read through the comments" is not a "solution" either. Comments often tend to get overlooked and deleted easily here, please post a detailed answer.

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same issue and this is really useful, and the comments from synacticgeorge up are the fix.

- Reboot
- On login screen, CTRL+ALT+F3 and login in TTY
- `nano .profile`   (or vi, gedit, whatever)
- Remove the offending brew line.
- Profit

Comment: Thanks, you're a life saver.

Answer (score 1):

do:
`$ nano ~/.profile`

go to end of the file, and comment out the following:

```
#if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
#    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
#fi
#eval $(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)
```

Finally save it:

```
Ctrl + X 
Y
Enter
sudo reboot now
```

you are good to go)

Answer (score -3):

You probably copied the install instructions and added homebrew to your path. If you remove the reference to homebrew from /home/user/.profile it should work again

type in terminal
rm -rf /home/[user]/.profile

Comment: This is really bad advice. You do realize that deleting ~/.profile on a default system will also disable the loading of your .bashrc?